# What is preventing find_library(c c) from setting the variable c in cmake?

Tags: cmake

In a bare CmakeLists.txt file, I place the following:

```
find_library (c c)
find_library (a c)
```

to match the syntax `find_library(<var> <lib>)`

I run `cmake .`
I open CMakeCache.txt and find a has been set with the path to libc, and c has not been set at all.

if I instead use `set (c "text" CACHE STRING "")` c will be set to "text"

Why can I set c with set() but not with find_library()?

Comment: Are given invocations (`find_library(a c)` and `find_library(a c)`) are **actually** *sequential*, or there are other command between them? Is neither `a` nor `c` variables set **elsewhere**? If so, remove `CMakeCache.txt` file and rerun CMake. After that you will have both `a` and `c` variables set in the same manner.

Comment: So this is working fine in multiple RHEL7 environments, (where the cmake was originally written) but fails specifically in a Debian environment.

Answer (score 0):

I've given your example a try and it seems to work just fine:

```perl
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4)

project(TestFindLibC NONE)

file(WRITE "libc.a" "")

find_library(
    c 
    NAMES c
    PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
find_library(
    a 
    NAMES c
    PATHS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}"
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)

message("c = ${c}")
message("a = ${c}")
```

Results in:

```
# cmake ..
c = [...]/libc.a
a = [...]/libc.a
```

So I'm with @Tsyvarev that your problems have to be in the not shown part of your CMake code. Try to add the following command to the top of your main `CMakeLists.txt` file to debug it:

```perl
variable_watch(a)
```

Comment: It seems to be a platform specific issue involving Debian.